# Loading page for ListView builder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, load, screen, loading

Hello I would like to have a loading page before all the list is created. To display this list, I get the request info in php and I create cards one by one. The problem is that when the user come on the application, there is a lot of loading round because I put "return CircularProgressIndicator()", I would like that we are on a waiting page until all the cards are not loaded

I tried to set variables and pass them to false until all the cards are loaded but I can't get on this loading page

Here is the code of my page

```
Future<String> getDataSearch(text, index) async {
  if (index != "ff") {
    var theUrl =
        Uri.parse("https://xf8s7auoez.preview.infomaniak.website/getdata.php");
    var res = await http.post(theUrl, body: {
      "index": index.toString(),
      "post": "index",
      "file": "get_data",
    });
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    if (text == 1) {
      return data["type"];
    } else if (text == 2) {
      return data["taille"];
    } else if (text == 3) {
      return data["prix"];
    } else if (text == 5) {
      return data["image"];
    } else if (text == 6) {
      return data["description"];
    }
  }
  var theUrl =
      Uri.parse("https://xf8s7auoez.preview.infomaniak.website/getdata.php");
  var res = await http.post(theUrl, body: {
    "post": "rows",
    "file": "get_data",
  });
  print(res.body);
  return res.body;
}

class Type extends StatelessWidget {
  Type(this.index);

  final int index;
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        // future: getUserType(index),
        future: getDataSearch(1, index),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return SizedBox(width: 10, height: 10, child: Container());
          }
        });
  }
}

class Description extends StatelessWidget {
  Description(this.index);

  final int index;
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        // future: getUserType(index),
        future: getDataSearch(6, index),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return SizedBox(width: 10, height: 10, child: Container());
          }
        });
  }
}

class Taille extends StatelessWidget {
  Taille(this.index);

  final int index;
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        // future: getUserType(index),
        future: getDataSearch(2, index),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text(snapshot.data!);
          } else {
            return SizedBox(width: 10, height: 10, child: Container());
          }
        });
  }
}

class Prix extends StatelessWidget {
  Prix(this.index);

  final int index;
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
        //future: getAge(index),
        future: getDataSearch(3, index),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            String bio = snapshot.data.toString();
            return Text(bio);
          } else {
            return SizedBox(width: 10, height: 10, child: Container());
          }
        });
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Mediester',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: RefreshIndicatorView(),
    );
  }
}

class RefreshIndicatorView extends StatefulWidget {
  const RefreshIndicatorView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _RefreshIndicatorViewState createState() => _RefreshIndicatorViewState();
}

class _RefreshIndicatorViewState extends State<RefreshIndicatorView> {
  int initNumber = 1;
  int selectedValue = 1;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _key = GlobalKey();
  @override
  initState() {
    getDataSearch(4, "ff").then((String result) {
      if (initNumber != int.parse(result)) {
        setState(() {
          initNumber = int.parse(result);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      displacement: 250,
      backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 155, 191),
      color: Colors.white,
      strokeWidth: 3,
      triggerMode: RefreshIndicatorTriggerMode.onEdge,
      onRefresh: () async {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1500));
        setState(() {
          int debug = 0;
        });
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _key,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 155, 191),
        appBar: BaseAppBar(),
        drawer: createDrawer(context),
        body: _buildCardDesign(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildCardDesign() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500), () {
      if (debugg != 1) {
        setState(() {});
        debugg = 1;
      }
    });
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: initNumber,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
              parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          prototypeItem: _buildCardView(1),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _buildCardView(index + 1);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPhoto(index) {
    return Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<String>(
            future: getDataSearch(5, index),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                  child: Image.network(
                    snapshot.data!,
                    height: 65.0,
                    width: 65.0,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
              }
            }));
  }

  Widget _buildCardView(index) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: 100,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => ArticlePage(
                      index, Type(index), Prix(index), Description(index)),
                ));
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 30, 15),
            child: Row(
              //  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                _buildPhoto(index),
                //SizedBox(width: 20,),
                DefaultTextStyle(
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 19,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 155, 191)),
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        DefaultTextStyle(
                            child: Container(child: Type(index)),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 110, 155, 191),
                                fontSize: 17)),
                        DefaultTextStyle(
                          child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                              child: Taille(index)),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 168, 168, 168)),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Prix(index),
                                Text(" €"),
                              ],
                            )),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). In your `RefreshIndicatorView` class, the `_buildCardDesign` widget is currently calling your future, and then building the ListView. Instead, try creating one async function that holds the logic for retrieving the data, and a separate class for the widget that is only responsible for building the widget. Then, you can call the future in the FutureBuilder and show your loading page until it has completed.

In the `FutureBuilder`, pass your function as the argument to `future`. Then you can use the variable `snapshot` to check the status of the future. In your `builder` function, simply check `if(snapshot.hasData)`, and show the loading page or the listView widget accordingly.

Edit: Here's a simple example that retrieves a `List<String>` and puts one `String` in each card. Your new function and widget class would look like this:

```
List<String> _getStrings() async {
  //Async logic here
  ...
}

Widget MyCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String displayText;
  myCard(this.displayText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(displayText);
  }
}
```

And in the home page of your MyApp, you can use something like this for the build method:

```
FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
  future: _getStrings,
  builder:  (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => MyCard(snapshot.data[index])
      ...
      );
    } else {
      return MyLoadingScreen();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sorry, I don't know how can I do that , i try to put the widget _buildCardDesign in a class and I create a function who create this class and give it to the main but i have an error, can you show me an example please?

Comment: Yup - updated answer with a short example

Comment: thanks for ur help, i have finally found how to do it !!!!

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.